# What happens to a "finalized" object if I make it available again?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Well, I tried making a *finalized* object *available again*. I know (from [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize())) that `finalize()` will not be called again on it. But what happens to it if it becomes *unreachable*?. *When will it be GCed?*.

Code :

```
public class Solution {
static ThreadGroup stg = null;
static Solution ss = null;

protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("finalized");
    System.out.println("this : " + this);
    ss = this;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Solution s = new Solution();
    s = null;
    System.gc();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(ss);
    ss = null;             // My question. What happens now?. Solution@7f5f5897 has just become unreachable. Will it be GCed without "finalize()" being called on it? (looks like that..). If yes, then how can I find out when exactly has it become eligible for gc (Please don't tell me to look at source code "==null" check :P)
    System.gc();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

O/P :

```
finalized
this : Solution@7f5f5897   // printed in finalize()
Solution@7f5f5897  // printed in main()
```

Comment: This is called *resurrection*.

Comment: @chrylis - Oh. Funny, Oracle docs doesn't mention this. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily an official term, since you're emphatically not supposed to do this, but it is possible, and people have managed to write programs that make the JVM flip out as a sort of exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will be GC'ed once it becomes unreachable the second time, except `finalize` will not be called on it again.

You can confirm this with a `WeakReference`.

```
static WeakReference<Solution> ref;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Solution s = new Solution();

    s = null;
    System.gc();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(ss);
    ref = new WeakReference<Jackson>(ss);
    ss = null; // My question. What happens now?. Solution@7f5f5897 has just become unreachable. Will it be GCed without "finalize()" being called
               // on it? (looks like that..). If yes, then how can I find out when exactly has it become eligible for gc (Please don't tell me to
               // look at source code "==null" check :P)
    System.out.println(ref.get()); // (hopefully) prints object
    System.gc();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(ref.get()); // prints null
}
```

So the `WeakReferenc` is cleared, showing that the object was GC'ed. (Technically, the `WeakReference` is cleared when the object becomes weakly reachable. But in this case, since you can't then make it reachable, it will get GC'ed.)

Comment: @TheLostMind You can tell after it's been GC'ed, but there's no notification of _when_.

Comment: Thanks :). That does *prove* that an Object becomes *weakly reachable* and *GCed (logically)* :P. I still don't get the *design* decision behind, *calling finalize only once* :P

Comment: @TheLostMind: The reason `finalize` is only called once is that *every* finalizable object which is abandoned will get resurrected (have a strong reference created to it) since a strong reference must exist while the `finalize` method runs.  There's no mechanism by which that resurrection could be distinguished from a more permanent form.  In .NET there is a method `ReRegisterForFinalize` which `Finalize` can use if it discovers that an object isn't ready to die yet, but no such mechanism exists in Java.