# Java GC does not gather a "zombie" object for a second time

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm

I am trying to create a mechanism to cache objects into memory, for future use, even if these objects are out of context. There would be a parallel deterministic process which will dictate (by a unique ID) whether the cached object should be retrieved again or if it should completely die. Here is the simplest example, with debug information to make things easier:

```
package com.panayotis.resurrect;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ZObject {

    private static int IDGEN = 1;

    protected int id;
    private boolean isKilled = false;

    public static final Map<Integer, ZObject> zombies = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.println("* INIT: " + new ZObject().toString());
        gc();
        sleep(1000);

        if (!zombies.isEmpty())
            ZObject.revive(2);

        gc();
        sleep(1000);

        if (!zombies.isEmpty())
            ZObject.kill(1);

        gc();
        sleep(1000);
        gc();
        sleep(1000);
        gc();
        sleep(1000);
        gc();
        sleep(1000);
    }

    public ZObject() {
        this.id = IDGEN++;
    }

    protected final void finalize() throws Throwable {
        String debug = "" + zombies.size();
        String name = toString();
        String style;
        if (!isKilled) {
            style = "* Zombie";
            zombies.put(id, this);
        } else {
            style = "*** FINAL ***";
            zombies.remove(id);
            super.finalize();
        }
        dumpZombies(style + " " + debug, name);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (isKilled ? "killed" : zombies.containsKey(id) ? "zombie" : "alive ") + " " + id;
    }

    public static ZObject revive(int peer) {
        ZObject obj = zombies.remove(peer);
        if (obj != null) {
            System.out.println("* Revive      " + obj.toString());
            obj.isKilled = false;
        } else
            System.out.println("* Not found as zombie " + peer);
        return obj;
    }

    public static void kill(int peer) {
        int size = zombies.size();
        ZObject obj = zombies.get(peer);
        String name = obj == null ? peer + " TERMINATED " : obj.toString();
        zombies.remove(peer);
        dumpZombies("*   Kill " + size, name);
        if (obj != null)
            obj.isKilled = true;
    }

    private static void dumpZombies(String baseMsg, String name) {
        System.out.println(baseMsg + "->" + zombies.size() + " " + name);
        for (Integer key : zombies.keySet())
            System.out.println("*             " + zombies.get(key).toString());
    }

    public static void gc() {
        System.out.println("* Trigger GC");
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            System.gc();
    }

    public static void sleep(int howlong) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(howlong);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

This code will create 5 objects, resurrect the first one and then kill the first one. I was expecting

- After first resurrection, and since the object doesn't have any more references yet, to re-enter zombie state through finalize (which it doesn't)
- After killing an object again to completely be removed from memory through again the finalize method

It seems, in other words, that finalize is called only once. I have checked that this is not a byproduct of the HashMap object with this code:

```
package com.panayotis.resurrect;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestMap {

    private static final HashMap<Integer, TestMap> map = new HashMap<>();

    private static int IDGEN = 1;
    private final int id;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        map.put(1, new TestMap(1));
        map.put(2, new TestMap(2));
        map.put(3, new TestMap(3));
        map.remove(1);
        System.out.println("Size: " + map.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            System.gc();
    }

    public TestMap(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Finalize " + id);
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

So, why this behavior? I am using Java 1.8

*EDIT* Since this is not directly possible, any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Based on your responses to my Answer, this seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: *"Since this is not directly possible, any ideas how I can accomplish this?"* - IMO, you need to explain clearly what "this" actually is.

Comment: I will create a new question, thank you for mentioning

Comment: Please have a look here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649865/lifecycle-of-mapping-of-native-resources-in-java-and-how-to-keep-them-in-sync

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to a "finalized" object if I make it available again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896718/what-happens-to-a-finalized-object-if-i-make-it-available-again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the specified behavior:

[Object.finalize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--)

> After the `finalize` method has been invoked for an object, no further action is taken until the Java virtual machine has again determined that there is no longer any means by which this object can be accessed by any thread that has not yet died, including possible actions by other objects or classes which are ready to be finalized, at which point the object may be discarded.
>
> The `finalize` method is never invoked more than once by a Java virtual machine for any given object.

You seem to have a wrong understanding of what the `finalize()` method does. This method does not free the object’s memory, declaring a custom non-trivial `finalize()` method is actually *preventing* the object’s memory from being freed as it has to be kept in memory for the execution of that method and afterwards, until the garbage collector has determined has it has become unreachable again. Not calling `finalize()` again does not imply that the object doesn’t get freed, it implies that it will be freed without calling `finalize()` again.

Instances of classes without a custom `finalize()` method or having a “trivial” finalize method (being empty or solely consisting of a `super.finalize()` call to another trivial finalizer) are not going through the finalization queue at all and are both, allocated faster and reclaimed faster.

That’s why you should never try to implement an object cache just for the memory, the result will always be less efficient than the JVM’s own memory management. But if you are managing an actually expensive resource, you may handle it by separating it into two different kinds of objects, a front-end providing the API to the application, which may get garbage collected whenever the application doesn’t use it, and a back-end object describing the actual resource, which is not directly seen by the application and may get reused.

It is implied that the resource is expensive enough to justify the weight of this separation. Otherwise, it’s not really a resource worth caching.

```
// front-end class
public class Resource {
    final ActualResource actual;

    Resource(ActualResource actual) {
        this.actual = actual;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return actual.getId();
    }
    public String toString() {
        return actual.toString();
    }
}
class ActualResource {
    int id;

    ActualResource(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ActualResource[id="+id+']';
    }
}
```

```
public class ResourceManager {
    static final ReferenceQueue<Resource> QUEUE = new ReferenceQueue<>();
    static final List<ActualResource> FREE = new ArrayList<>();
    static final Map<WeakReference<?>,ActualResource> USED = new HashMap<>();
    static int NEXT_ID;

    public static synchronized Resource getResource() {
        for(;;) {
            Reference<?> t = QUEUE.poll();
            if(t==null) break;
            ActualResource r = USED.remove(t);
            if(r!=null) FREE.add(r);
        }
        ActualResource r;
        if(FREE.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("allocating new resource");
            r = new ActualResource(NEXT_ID++);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("reusing resource");
            r = FREE.remove(FREE.size()-1);
        }
        Resource frontEnd = new Resource(r);
        USED.put(new WeakReference<>(frontEnd, QUEUE), r);
        return frontEnd;
    }
    /**
     * Allow the underlying actual resource to get garbage collected with r.
     */
    public static synchronized void stopReusing(Resource r) {
        USED.values().remove(r.actual);
    }
    public static synchronized void clearCache() {
        FREE.clear();
        USED.clear();
    }
}
```

Note that the manager class may have arbitrary methods for controlling the caching or manual release of resources, the methods above are just examples. If your API supports the front-end to become invalid, e.g. after calling `close()`, `dispose()` or such alike, immediate explicit freeing or reuse can be provided without having to wait for the next gc cycle. While `finalize()` is called exactly one time, you can control the number of reuse cycles here, including the option of enqueuing *zero* times.

Here is some test code

```
static final ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Resource r1 = manager.getResource();
    Resource r2 = manager.getResource();
    System.out.println("r1 = "+r1+", r2 = "+r2);
    r1 = null;
    forceGC();

    r1 = manager.getResource();
    System.out.println("r1 = "+r1);
    r1 = null;
    forceGC();

    r1 = manager.getResource();
    System.out.println("r1 = "+r1);

    manager.stopReusing(r1);

    r1 = null;
    forceGC();

    r1 = manager.getResource();
    System.out.println("r1 = "+r1);
}
private static void forceGC() {
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++ ) try {
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex){}
}
```

Which will likely (`System.gc()` still isn’t guaranteed to have an effect) print:

```
allocating new resource
allocating new resource
r1 = ActualResource[id=0], r2 = ActualResource[id=1]
reusing resource
r1 = ActualResource[id=0]
reusing resource
r1 = ActualResource[id=0]
allocating new resource
r1 = ActualResource[id=2]
```

Comment: Indeed this is the case: to handle very costly resources, which are not possible to retrieve otherwise, or else I know all that effort dos not worth it and practically isn't optimized. The reason I haven't picked up the double-class solution like this, is what if we create a new inherited front-end object? Then the data stored in the front-end object isn't lost?

Comment: Every data you want to reuse must be reachable through the back-end resource object. This doesn’t preclude mirroring; both may have a reference to these data. But then, care must be taken not to allow the gc to collect the front-end object while the other data is still being used, as aggressive optimizations allow this, even if all access appears to be done through the front-end object from a source code’s perspective. Seriously, manual resource management is simpler and more robust in most cases even if it’s so tempting to try to use the JVM’s reachability analysis for managing resources…

Comment: I know but the problem is like this - as I said to the other comment maybe it is better to create a new question to clearly state the requirements instead of trying to solve the problem with wrong assumptions.

Comment: I wrote the actual requirements here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649865/lifecycle-of-mapping-of-native-resources-in-java-and-how-to-keep-them-in-sync

Answer (score 1):

You should not implement the finalize method, as the GC will call it only once for each instance.

So if the GC will find an object to delete, it will call  the finalize. Then it will check again for maybe new references. It might find one and keep the object in the memory.

On the next run, the same object will, again, not have any references. The GC will just kill it, it will *not* call the finalize again.

Comment: I know all the reasons that "I should not override the finalize method". There is a good article about it. https://web.archive.org/web/20111015052835/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/finalization/  But this is not the question

Comment: But... no, that is exaclty what you asked. You wrote `It seems, in other words, that finalize is called only once.` and `So, why this behavior?`. And the answer to your question is, that the GC will call the finalize only once. This is not a bug, it is a sepcified requierement to be fulfilled by the VM.

Comment: So, to put things into context, is there any way to gc a "zombie" reference like this otherwise?

Comment: It's an interessting use-case you got there. I don't have a 100% fitting answer, but maybe one of the reference objects might be helpful for you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html See the three sub types Phantom, Soft and Weak Reference.

Comment: None of them seem to work: Phantom is called *after* finalize is called, Soft is a way to prevent OutOfMemory and Weak... well... it doesn't really keep a consistent reference at all

Answer (score 1):

You know what?

I think that your **stated** requirements would simply be satisfied by a concurrent map.

> I am trying to create a mechanism to cache objects into memory, for future use, even if these objects are out of context.

That is simply a map, with the ID as the key; e.g.

```
Map<IdType, ValueType> cache = new HashMap<>();
```

When you create an object that needs to be cached, you simply call `cache.put(id, object)`.  It will remain cached until you remove it.

> There would be a parallel deterministic process which will dictate (by a unique ID) whether the cached object should be retrieved again or if it should completely die.

That's a thread ("parallel deterministic process") that calls `cache.remove(id)`.

Now, if you remove an object from the cache and it is still in use somewhere else (i.e. it is still *reachable*) then it won't be garbage collected.  But that is OK.  But is shouldn't be!

---

But what about that stuff with `finalize()`?

As far as I can see, it does not contribute to your **stated** requirement at all.  Your code seems to detecting objects that are destined to be deleted, and making them reachable (your `zombies` list).  That seems to be the opposite of your requirements.

- If the purpose of the `finalize()` is simply to track when the `Zombie` objects are actually deleted, then `finalize()` is only ever called once, so it can't do that.  But, why is the `finalize()` method adding the object to the `zombie` list?
- If your requirements are actually misstated and you are *really* trying to create "immortal" objects (i.e. objects that cannot be deleted), then a plain `Map` will do that.   Just don't remove the object's key, and it will "live" for ever.

---

Now implementing a cache as a plain map risks creating a memory leak.  There are a couple of ways to address that:

- You can create a subclass of `LinkedHashMap`, and implement `removeEldestEntry()` to tell the map when to remove the oldest entry if the cache has too many entries; see the javadocs for details.
- You can implement a cache as a `HashMap<SoftReference<IdType>, ValueType>` and use a `ReferenceQueue` to remove cache entries whose references have been broken by the GC.  (Note that soft references will be broken by the GC when a key is no longer strongly reachable, *and* memory is running short.)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a simple cache system, and it is not a thread, it is some native code which could hold a reference for unknown time and might release it's it in unknown time also. The tricky part is that there is a need to inform the native system that Java doesn't need it any more, but it is important the Java object to be alive as long as the native part wants it.  [ maybe create a separate question for this scenario? ]

Comment: Well perhaps you need to restate your requirements.  In fact, I think you will get more pertinent answers if you ask a brand new Question.  Focus on explaining your actual requirements ... rather than asking for an explanation of why finalize is not doing what you think it should do.

Comment: I wrote the actual requirements here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649865/lifecycle-of-mapping-of-native-resources-in-java-and-how-to-keep-them-in-sync